# Where to find official sources for price-to-rent ratio?

Tags: data-request, property

Where can I find price-to-rent ratio data for housing real estate in any major nation?

Any G-20 country or any [top-10 country by GDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)) would be good for me, as long as it's official data like from a country's census or statistical bureau.

Comment: You're talking about real estate, right? Specifically, housing? Or would this include commercial properties as well?

Comment: @nathanwww yes, housing

Comment: It might be easier to find some city-level data.